# Filesystem slowly fills up with tmp file

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem, webserver

My server HD will fill up in about 48 hours. I then reboot it to clear it back up. There's no visibly large files.

I think it's filling up with deleted or tmp files that are not released by the processes.

If I do

```
lsof -b 2>/dev/null | grep deleted
```

I get a long list where these stand out:

```
cron      12349    root    5u      REG  253,1 7540951006      29447 /tmp/tmpfmbHMqy (deleted)
sh        12355    root    1u      REG  253,1 7540951876      29447 /tmp/tmpfmbHMqy (deleted)
sh        12355    root    2u      REG  253,1 7540951876      29447 /tmp/tmpfmbHMqy (deleted)
bash      12357    root    1u      REG  253,1 7540951876      29447 /tmp/tmpfmbHMqy (deleted)
bash      12357    root    2u      REG  253,1 7540951876      29447 /tmp/tmpfmbHMqy (deleted)
```

If I'm not mistaken, these are 7gb each? If that large number is the file size?

Where do I go from here?

**[update]**

Thanks for the suggestions.

@muru, this is the output

```
 pstree -pa 12355
sh,12355 -c /home/git/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload    /home/root/mysql_BU/ backup/mysql_BU/
  |-> bash,12357 /home/git/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /home/root/mysql_BU/ backup/mysql_BU/
```

I looked at my crontab and the thing that stand out it that it's set to upload a mysql-dump to dropbox.

```
0 3 * * * /home/git/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /root/backup/mysql backup/mysql_BU/
```

However, this is a new instance of the server and the dropbox-upload seem to not be configured and the source directory does not exist. So I changed it and made sure that command actually does something.

I think that running the dropbox_uploader.sh created a 'prompt' where it waits for user input (it asks for dropbox api keys and such) and I can imagine this leaking memory over time? I just restarted the server, we'll see tomorrow if it worked.

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in your cron tab?

Comment: Run `pstree -pa 12355` and add the output, please. (If you have rebooted since, pick the PID of the `sh` process that comes between cron and the bash processes

Comment: please add result of `crontab -l`

Comment: That is 1 7Gb file (with different processes).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mistake with your fstab, since files in /tmp are supposed to not be on the hard drive. Can you post the content of the /etc/fstab file? It would help a lot.

I know this should have been posted as a comment, but I am unable to post those.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right there. I have files in my `/tmp` directory on my hard drive. They get deleted with a cron job.

Comment: /tmp is not a special filesystem; all it has is 777 permissions and sticky bit set.

Comment: Some distros use tmpfs for tmp, but Ubuntu doesn't by default